# How to read a dataframe in np.genfromtxt instead of a file in matplotlib

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I am new to matplotlib and I am trying to plot a simple graph with x-axis as time/date and y-axis as a variable that has a list of values(numbers) along with PASS,FAIL and BLOCKED values. The dataframe that I am plotting graph for is as below:

```
  indeces      Zeitstempel     Ergebnis
0   382    16.04.2020 16:12:07  PASS
1   383    16.04.2020 16:13:07  PASS
2   392    16.04.2020 16:13:20  FAIL
3   382    16.04.2020 16:13:22  PASS
4   383    16.04.2020 16:14:22  PASS
```

There are 1172 rows × 3 columns. I have shown some here.
Below is the code I am trying and this gives me 'TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not bytes'

```
# Converter function
datefunc = lambda x: mdates.date2num(datetime.strptime(x, '%d %m %Y %H %M %S'))

# Read data from df
Time, Index = np.genfromtxt(df,    # Data to be read
                            delimiter=19,  # First column is 19 characters wide
                            converters={0: datefunc}, # Formatting of column 0
                            dtype=float,   # All values are floats
                            unpack=True)   # Unpack to several variables

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Configure x-ticks
ax.set_xticks(Time) # Tickmark + label at every plotted point
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))

ax.plot_date(Time, Index, ls='-', marker='o')
ax.set_title('title')
ax.set_ylabel('Index_Num')
ax.grid(True)

# Format the x-axis for dates (label formatting, rotation)
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)
fig.tight_layout()

fig.show()
```

Time has **df.Zeistempel** values and Index has **df.indeces** values.
I want to plot all three columns in the dataframe in a graph to show which index is passing or failing or being blocked at what time. Is there any simpler way to do this? I am aware that the df argument in read the data section is causing the issue. The type should be str not byte I believe but could someone please tell me how can I pass dataframe instead of the file to read the data.

Comment: in you already have a dataframe, you don't need `genfromtext`

Comment: but I did try not using np array for this somehow it gives me Keyerror

Comment: `genfromtxt` loads a csv style file, or equivalent **text** (list of lines).  A dataframe is not text, though it might have loaded from a csv itself.  If you have problems plotting from the frame address that issue.

Comment: You can select columns of the dataframe, e.g.`df[indeces]`.  `values` or `to_numpy()` can be used to extract values as arrays (1 or 2d).  I haven't paid attention to what you are trying to do with the dates, but I think `pandas` has more powerful date conversion tools than `numpy`.

Comment: @codepy Are you still working on this? Is `df` in your code above a reference to a pandas dataframe or "csv" formatted file?  `np.genfromtext` reads from a file (path/filename defined by `df`). If you are reading from a file, I suspect the TypeError for your strptime() argument is a result of the float dtype used in `np.genfromtext`.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. df is a pandas dataframe that has extracted data from a database and I realised that there is no way I could use np.genfromtext for extracting data from df so I am trying to find another approach.

Comment: Ok, understood. It's possible to do the datetime string conversion to float if you read the data from a csv file. (Your code is close, but needs some tweaking.)

Comment: @kcw78 yes but finding it difficult to figure out. I have posted another question https://stackoverflow.com/q/66874999/15398763 here, changing the approach but somehow no views for that question at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know OP wants to plot data from a Pandas dataframe (not a NumPy array created with  `np.genfromtxt`). That said, the process to create the desired plot from CSV data is very similar. This process stores the data in a NumPy recarray. So, if one maps the Pandas data appropriately, it can be adapted to the desired workflow. (I don't know Pandas, so can't help in that regard).

This workflow demonstrates several useful techniques, including: 1) `np.genfromtxt converters=` argument with a lambda function, 2) `np.where()` with a recarray, and 3) fancy indexing with the results.  These 3 steps are used to separate the 3 'Ergebnis' values to use different colored markers for each value.

I added data points to those in the question so there are 'Ergebnis'='BLOCKED' values (as mentioned in the related post linked in the comments). Resulting image is my interpretation of the plot request. See below:
[image]

Code to create the plot is below. It's not clear (to me) what the data in the first column represents. It's a trivial piece of data, so for simplicity I imported as field 'i' and ignored. I suspect `np.genfromtxt` parameters can be adjusted to skip over that field.

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# Converter function
datefunc = lambda x: mdates.date2num(datetime.strptime(x.strip(), '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'))
csv = 'SO_66872155.csv'
# Read data from csv file
csv_arr = np.genfromtxt(csv,    # Data to be read
                        delimiter=',',  # use comma
                        converters={2: datefunc}, # Formatting of column 2
                        dtype=None,
                        autostrip=True,
                        encoding=None,
                        names=True)   

print(csv_arr.dtype)
  
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

e_flag_List = ['PASS', 'FAIL', 'BLOCKED']
e_colors = ['green', 'red', 'grey']
x_arrs = []
y_arrs = []
for e_flag in e_flag_List:
    r_idx = np.where(csv_arr['Ergebnis']==e_flag)
    x_arr = csv_arr[r_idx[0].tolist()]['Zeitstempel']
    x_arrs.append(x_arr)
    y_arr = csv_arr[r_idx[0].tolist()]['indeces']
    y_arrs.append(y_arr)    

ax.set_title('Ergebnis Status Plot')
ax.grid(True)

# Configure x-axis
Time = csv_arr['Zeitstempel']
ax.set_xticks(Time) # Tickmark + label at every plotted point
ax.set_xlabel('Date-Time')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))
# Format the x-axis for dates (label formatting, rotation)
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)
fig.tight_layout()

# Configure y-axis
ax.set_ylabel('Index')

for i, e_flag in enumerate(e_flag_List):
    Time  = x_arrs[i]
    Index = y_arrs[i]
    ax.plot_date(Time, Index, linestyle='None', marker='o', mec=e_colors[i],mfc=e_colors[i])
```

CSV data I used is below. Data was added, along with comma delimiters.

```
i,  indeces,   Zeitstempel,         Ergebnis
0,    382,    16.04.2020 16:12:07,  PASS
1,    383,    16.04.2020 16:13:17,  PASS
2,    384,    16.04.2020 16:13:20,  BLOCKED
2,    392,    16.04.2020 16:13:33,  FAIL
3,    382,    16.04.2020 16:13:44,  PASS
4,    383,    16.04.2020 16:14:22,  PASS
5,    394,    16.04.2020 16:15:33,  BLOCKED
```