# KeyError while plotting a graph in matplotlib

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-lab

I am trying to plot a simple graph for the dataframe below

```
  indeces      Zeitstempel     Ergebnis
0   382    16.04.2020 16:12:07  PASS
1   383    16.04.2020 16:13:07  PASS
2   392    16.04.2020 16:13:20  FAIL
3   382    16.04.2020 16:13:22  PASS
4   383    16.04.2020 16:14:22  PASS
```

It has three columns. The x-axis should be Zeitstempel, y-axis should be indeces and I would also want to specify the values in Ergebnis column(maybe color coding green for PASS,red for FAIL and grey for BLOCKED)
as to which index is passing or failing or blocking at what time. The actual dataframe has 1172 rows × 3 columns values but in the above i have only mentioned few.
The code I am trying is as below but somehow I am not able to figure out how to plot all the 3 as required.

```
times = pd.date_range('2020-04-16 04:12 AM', '2020-04-16 11:00 PM', freq='1H')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
fig.autofmt_xdate()

df.plot(kind='line',x='times',y='Index',ax=ax)
xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
ax = plt.gca()

plt.show()
```

times has Zeitstempel values and Index has indeces values stored in them. This gives me KeyError. Is there a simpler way to do this? I am new to matplotlib and I am running out of possibilities. Please suggest.

Comment: `x,y` refers to column names in your dataframe, e.g. `Zeitstempel, indeces`.

Comment: @QuangHoang  yes and I tried to store those values in times and Index variable respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the answer I posted at: [How to read a dataframe in np.genfromtxt instead of a file in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66908315/10462884). It shows how to load data from a csv file with `np.genfromtxt()` then generate the desired color coded plot (similar to what you want to do). If you can map your Pandas data to a NumPy recarray, the rest of the process will still work the same.

I'm not familiar with Pandas, so can only supply pseudo-code. It will look something like this. Replace this call to `np.genfromtxt()` (that reads the csv data from a file):

```
csv_arr = np.genfromtxt(csv,    # Data to be read
                        ...)
```

With the following lines to create the recarray. (I reused the `csv_arr` name to simplify. Feel free to use any name you like):

```
csv_dt = np.dtype([ ('indeces', '<i4'), ('Zeitstempel', 'O'), ('Ergebnis', '<U7') ])
csv_arr = np.empty(shape=(nrows,), dtype=csv_dt)
csv_arr['Zeitstempel'] = # pandas Zeitstempel data goes here as a numpy array
csv_arr['indeces'] = # pandas indeces data goes here as a numpy array 
csv_arr['Ergebnis'] = # pandas Ergebnis data goes here as a numpy array
```

After you add your Pandas data to `csv_arr`, the rest of the code should work the same and create the same plot shown in the referenced answer. Good luck.